# Laravel: update function creating new record instead of updating existing one

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hi guys i am trying to update my existing record in my edit page..so when i clicked on update button it is creating new record instead of  updating existing one

Here is my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Qtype_editor $qtype_editor)
{

    $qtype_editor = new Qtype_editor();
    $qtype_editor->qtype_name = $request->input('qtype_name');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_subject_id = $request->input('qtype_subject_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_topic_id = $request->input('qtype_topic_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_option = $request->input('qtype_option');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_json = $request->input('qtype_json');
    $qtype_editor->sort_order = $request->input('sort_order');
    $qtype_editor->save();

    return redirect()->route('eqtype-editor.index');
}
```

And i have ajax call where i am updating records from ajax
Here is my ajax code

```
  function saveEditQtypeFile(edit_qtype_id)
    {
       $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

        chk_EnumValuesValidation = chkEnumValuesValidation(isSoltion, stepCount);
        if(!chk_EnumValuesValidation)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
    // Function to push "MainArray" in current Solution
     pushVarMainArrayInThisSolution(isSoltion, var_main_arr.var_arr_values);

    arr                = ar;
    var edit_qtype_id = $('#edit_qtype_id').val();
    var qtype_name = $('#qtype_name').val();
    var subject_list   = $('#qtype_subject_id').val();
    var ddl_topic_type = $('#qtype_topic_id').val();
    var qtype_option = $('#qtype_option').val();
    var jasondata = $('#qtype_json').val();
    var sort_order = $('#sort_order').val();
    var jasondata = $('#jasonData').val();

    var sendInfo       = {
        'edit_qtype_id':edit_qtype_id,
        'arr':arr,
        'saveEditQtypeFile':1,
        'qtype_name':qtype_name,
        'qtype_subject_id':subject_list,
        'qtype_topic_id':ddl_topic_type,
        'qtype_option':qtype_option,
        'qtype_json':jasondata,
        'sort_order':sort_order
    };
    console.log(sendInfo);
      //var loadQtypeInfo = JSON.stringify(sendInfo);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/eqtype-editor/update",
        type: "POST",
        data :sendInfo,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

        success: function(response)
        {
            alert('Your file is updated!');

        },
    error: function (request, status, error)
    {
        alert('problem with updating record!!!');
    },
    complete: function()
    {}
});
}
```

}

Here is my route file:

```
Route::post('eqtype-editor/update', 'QtypeEditorController@update');
```

Can anyone help me where i did mistake..thanks in advance.

Comment: `$qtype_editor = new Qtype_editor();` You're literally creating a new `Qtype_editor` here.

Comment: You should already have your `$qtype_editor` from your method parameter. Also, the method for updating should be `PUT/PATCH`, not `POST`

Comment: yeah didnt check that actually..thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve update of records

**One - minor change in your code to just get it working**

```php
public function update(Request $request, Qtype_editor $qtype_editor)
{

    $qtype_editor = Qtype_editor::findOrFail($request->edit_qtype_id);
    $qtype_editor->qtype_name = $request->input('qtype_name');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_subject_id = $request->input('qtype_subject_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_topic_id = $request->input('qtype_topic_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_option = $request->input('qtype_option');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_json = $request->input('qtype_json');
    $qtype_editor->sort_order = $request->input('sort_order');
    $qtype_editor->save();

    return redirect()->route('eqtype-editor.index');
}
```

**Second:
Following Laravel conventions - The Laravel Way**

Route definition should be: PUT/PATCH methods for resource update

```php
Route::match(
    ['PUT', "PATCH'],
    'eqtype-editor/{qtype_editor}', //qtype_editor param for route model binding
    'QtypeEditorController@update'
);
```

```php
public function update(Request $request, Qtype_editor $qtype_editor)
{
    //$qtype_editor will be resolved via route model binding
    //object representing db record with id of $qtype_editor passed from frontend
    //$qtype_editor = Qtype_editor::findOrFail($request->edit_qtype_id);

    $qtype_editor->qtype_name = $request->input('qtype_name');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_subject_id = $request->input('qtype_subject_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_topic_id = $request->input('qtype_topic_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_option = $request->input('qtype_option');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_json = $request->input('qtype_json');
    $qtype_editor->sort_order = $request->input('sort_order');
    $qtype_editor->save();

    return redirect()->route('eqtype-editor.index');
}
```

Javascript

```js
$.ajax({
    url: `/eqtype-editor/${edit_qtype_id}`, //add the id to the route
    type: "PUT",
    data :sendInfo,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

    success: function(response)
    {
        alert('Your file is updated!');

    },
    error: function (request, status, error)
    {
        alert('problem with updating record!!!');
    },
    complete: function()
    {}
});
```

Comment: There's no reason to do a `find` or `findOrFail`. `$qtype_editor` is already being passed to the function.

Comment: OP is not using a route with route parameter so implicit route model binding will not be available @ceejayoz

Comment: OP should fix that in the route, then.